# Web-server on Azure

Tags: software-installation, apache2

I installed an Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS Virtual MAchine on Azure.

I want to set it up as a WebServer with email capabilities, too.

How can I install software packages through the command line? Is there a list of available packages?

Thanks,
Yiannis

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `apt-get` and `apt-cache` commands will be your friends.

First of all, to be sure to have an up-to-date list of software available in the Ubuntu repositories configured on your server, you will to run the `sudo apt-get update` command.

If you don't know the exact name of a package, you will have to search for it. For instance, searching for all instance of *apache* in the list of software, you will do `apt-cache search apache`.

When you have identified the name of the package(s) you need, you will do `sudo apt-get install <package name>`.

The `apt-get` command retrieve the name of all the dependent packages and will install them along with the package you have requested.

There are alternative to `apt-get`.
The one I like, is `tasksel`. Install it by typing `sudo apt-get tasksel`.

`tasksel` can be used to install all the packages related to a given functionality. Not only the dependencies, but also nice-to-have tools to create for instance a LAMP server and so on.

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo tasksel install mail-server
```

will install all the required packages that will create a full-featured mail and LAMP server.